# Symmetrical number function not working as expected

Tags: c

```
bool problem30(int n){
    bool result = false;
    char* a = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    sprintf(a, "%c", n);
    int lengh = strlen(a);
    for (int i = 0; i <= lengh; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == a[lengh - i - 1])
        {    
            return true;
        }   return false;
    }
```

I want to check for symmetrical numbers in the above function but when I run the code, all the numbers return symmetrical and I don't know where I have gone wrong.

Could some one please help me to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: What test cases did you try?

Comment: I think you want `sprintf(a, "%d", n);`

Comment: As a hint: your `for` loop will only execute one time before the whole function is exited.

Comment: how to fix ```for``` loop in there ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with the function.

Firstly "return" is returning on the first pair regardless of what the rest of the number is.

**For Example:** 7657 isn't symmetrical however as your function returns on the first loop it will say it is. This can be fix by instead setting result "true". In fact I would start with result == true and test if it was not symmetrical.

Secondly your malloc expression is a bit excessive, but on the right track. Malloc takes bytes anyway a size_of(char) == size_of(byte)... but both of these are not required as "Malloc takes bytes"

Something like this (updated /w libraries and main):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

bool problem30(int n){
    bool result = true;
    char* a = (char *)malloc(100);
    sprintf(a, "%d", n);
    
    int length = strlen(a);
    for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != a[length - i - 1])
        {    
            result = false;
        }  
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    // Example 1
    printf("%d\n",problem30(7558));
    
    // Example 2
    printf("%d\n",problem30(7557));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good effort and well formatted, but a couple of notes. Longest `int` can be is 11-char with `+/-` included, so `char a[16];` is more than sufficient (preventing possible memory leak). Next, no need to declare `bool result ...;` in your loop simply replace `result = false;` with `return false;` (there is no need to iterate further after you determine it's not a palindrome). After the function, simply `return true;` There is no need for `strlen()` simply use `int length = sprintf(a, "%d", n);` (which returns the number of characters written, excluding the null byte, i.e. `strlen()`)

Comment: Can u explain for me in the first problem? I tried to fix like your code but this is not success.

Comment: @Dinosour you'll have to be a bit more specific about what you need help with. 

I have attached a link to an example of the code running online, I have not applied DavidC.Rankin's suggestions to the code, however I would highly recommend you take his comments onboard.

C Code: https://codeshare.io/wnXJn9
C++ Code: https://codeshare.io/Jbjxb6

I have update my code in the original post to reflect C++ code above.

Comment: @Dinosour just realised you specified 'c', updated original answer to 'c'.

Comment: @JordanHumphries thank you for your response. I'll read it.